# Aggregation of time-series data on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, downsampling

```
                     rand_val  new_val           copy_time
2020-10-15 00:00:00         7       26 2020-10-15 00:00:00
2020-10-15 00:00:10         8       29 2020-10-15 00:00:10
2020-10-15 00:00:20         1       53 2020-10-15 00:00:20
2020-10-15 00:03:50         6       69 2020-10-15 00:03:50
2020-10-15 00:04:00         3       19 2020-10-15 00:04:00
```

I am using the method resample to downsample the time-series. I have found I cannot call the specific columns when applying a function on the aggregated data.

Let's say I want to do some operation that involves calling the name of a column:

```
df.resample("1min").apply(lambda x: sum(x.rand_val) if len(x)>1 else 0)
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rand_val'
```

This would be possible if I had done groupby on some other variable. I guess the resample function is not the same. Any ideas?

Comment: try `df.resample('1min',on='copy_time').apply(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question!. When we do `groupby` certain columns, each chunk of data is treated as a pandas DataFrame. So, we can access a column like how we normally do. But, in this case of `resample`, it's a series.

One way of obtaining only for `rand_val` would be to pass that series directly as follows:

```
df.resample("1min")['rand_val'].apply(lambda x: sum(x) if len(x)>1 else 0)
```

I'm assuming your index is in date-time format. Else please convert it using `pd.to_datetime` as follows:

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `on=copy_time`, i got the following output.

```
a = df.resample('1min',on='copy_time').apply(lambda x: sum(x.rand_val) if len(x)>1 else 0)
print (a)
```

[resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) is looking for an object that must have a datetime-like index. In your example, I didn't see that. Passing `copy_time` would give that datatime series to process.

```
             org_time  rand_val  new_val           copy_time
0 2020-10-15 00:00:00         7       26 2020-10-15 00:00:00
1 2020-10-15 00:00:10         8       29 2020-10-15 00:00:10
2 2020-10-15 00:00:20         1       53 2020-10-15 00:00:20
3 2020-10-15 00:03:50         6       69 2020-10-15 00:03:50
4 2020-10-15 00:04:00         3       19 2020-10-15 00:04:00


copy_time
2020-10-15 00:00:00    16
2020-10-15 00:01:00     0
2020-10-15 00:02:00     0
2020-10-15 00:03:00     0
2020-10-15 00:04:00     0
Freq: T, dtype: int64
```

Comment: My index is of datetime object. By default it looks to down-sample on the index.